# Terminal Server 2008 - Slow File open dialog in Office 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, microsoft-office, windows-server-2003, dialog

I have yet another small issue that annoys me everyday in our Terminal Server environment.

It seems when logging into Terminal Server users report the initial File | Open or File | Save As from within an application such as Word, Excel (2003 edition) is very slow to display the actual dialog box.

The dialog appears quickly but it is whited out (sometimes displays not responding in title bar) and unresponsive, it then sits like this for about 20-30 secs before popping into life and displaying all the folders etc.

The second time you go to save or open a file it loads almost instantly.

Any suggestions or similar problems out there?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any mapped network drives? I belive that the slow in the first time, is because the system is checking the permissions (user/password) to open this mapped drivers..

Comment: Yes, each user has between 2-3 mapped drives. Any known work arounds out there or do we just live with the small delay?

Comment: Well, you can check:
- if all mapped drives is working correctly (user/password);
- If there is an Antivirus software (and it configured to check these mapped drives) and/or backup software (agent?) that monitoring these mapped drives;
- Network troughtput between TS and the servers with mapped drives;
- Authentication process (AD/GPO)?

You can make a test: disable these mapped drivers for one user to verify if the slowness is because of network.